# error C2678: '==' binary: no operator found which takes a left operand of type 'CSchemaString' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

I am transferring a project from `VC++6` to `VC++ 2005`, and on compilation I get the following error.

> error C2678: '==' binary: no operator found which takes a left operand
>   of type 'CSchemaString' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

HERE IS THE CODE;

```
CSchemaString References("id");
for(j=0;j<=tpChild.GetUpperBound();j++)
{
    if(References == "id") //error C2678: '==' binary: no operator found which takes a left operand of type 'CSchemaString' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

        References = References + intToString(((Component*)tpChild.GetAt(j))->GetComponentID()) +"_"+ ((Component*)tpChild.GetAt(j))->GetName();
    else
        References = References + " id" + intToString(((Component*)tpChild.GetAt(j))->GetComponentID()) +"_"+((Component*)tpChild.GetAt(j))->GetName();
}
if(References != "id") //si references n'est pas vide
    XComponent.AddPlant_Item_Ref(References);



return XComponent;
```

}

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

A CSchemaString isn't a string. You'd need to do

```
References.ToString() == "id"
```